# .o files and the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

If I do a kernel build and in some directory there are a host of .o files that were generated. Is it safe to assume that any of the .c files which did not generate a .o file are not being used?

Comment: To much generic or incomplete question. Which .o files of Linux Kernel? What is your target architecture? What you are trying to do and what is the question in it?

Comment: @Parthiban Pretty generic question. Looking for a yes/no and not looking to add any more detail than I have already.

Comment: No, it is not safe. Some objects might be removed by the build process. Some C files might be used only with specific config etc..

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Okay great that's what I needed to know ty!